# Java: Adding Inputs to a Linked List

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, singly-linked-list

I am trying to add inputs into a linked list. The inputs come from a file. I can print out the values, but only the first value is being added to the linked list. Not sure what I am missing. Everything should be written from scratch. Any help appreciated.

```
        public void addNode(int data) {
            Node newNode = new Node(data);

            if(head == null) {
                head = newNode;
                tail = newNode;
            }
        }

        public void display() {
            Node current = head;
            System.out.println("Nodes of a Singly linked list: ");
            while (current != null) {

                System.out.print(current.data + " -> ");
                current = current.next;
            }
           
        }
```

results:

```
Nodes of a Singly linked list: 
1 ->
```

Comment: your add Function is wrong you need to link it to a new Node as well using `head.next = newNode`.

Comment: Look at your `addNode(int data)` method — if `head==null` you point head & tail to the new node. Fine. But if head is NOT null you _don't do anything_. You have no "else" clause. So nodes after that first one get created as a `Node`, but nothing is ever done with them. They are just dropped off into space.

Comment: @StephenP Good explanation, implementation of it is below.

Comment: @StephenP Thanks, this was really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because your `addNode()` function is not correct, check the below implementation.

```java
     public void addNode(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);

        if(head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;

        }
```

Comment: The above code is wrong - because tail is never updated AND 2 nodes are created in most cases...  the else block can be simplified as `tail.next = newNode; tail = newNode;`

Comment: @MrR Thank you! This is correct. I've fixed my code according to you & StephenP's response. It works now.

Comment: @MrR it has been a while since I manually implemented a LinkedList, took your comment into consideration, there were two nodes created because of me not paying attention to the copied code... Thank you